# How to add data to a json file while making use of multiproccesing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using a user-friendly json based document oriented database named [TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But I'm unable to add multiple pieces of data to my database because I'm making use of multiproccesing. After a while I get the error that id x already exists in the database (this because 2 or more processes are trying to add data at the same time). Is there any way to solve this?

Every run I insert new unique params.

Example params:

```py
params = {'id' = 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}
```

Code:

```py
resultsDb = TinyDB('db/resultsDb.json')

def run(params):
    resultsDb.insert({'id': params['id'], 'name': params['name'], 'age': params['age']})

maxProcesses = 12 # Cores in my pc

for i in range(maxProcesses):
    processes.append(Process(target=run, args=(params,)))

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Comment: First, you are missing a `'` in `params['id]`. Second, your code as shown is passing the same value of `params`, which you do not show, to all 12 processes. Is this really your actual code? If so, of course you will get a duplicate id error even if you did not use multiprocessing. Or do you have a list of params? And can I assume this is Linux/Unix?

Comment: Okay I've updated it. No this isn't my actual code to make it not that difficult. I've added an example params dict. Yeah I'm using Linux.

Comment: Have you actually read [Why Not Use TinyDB?](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#why-not-use-tinydb)

Comment: See the comment by @HTF and then see my answer below which verifies that multiprocessing and multithreading is incompatible with `TinyDB`. I got it to work but had to serialize insertions with a `Lock`, which defeats the whole purpose of multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not test this on a Linux system that I have access to because it is a shared server on which certain facilities required to run the code have been forbidden access. This is a Windows version below. But the key features are:

1. It uses a `Lock` to ensure that the insertions are serialized, which I believe is necessary for it to run without error. This, of course, defeats the purpose of parallelizing your code and one can conclude that there is really no point in using multiprocessing or multithreading.
2. In Windows I did not have to move the `resultsDb = TinyDB('db.json')` statement to within the `run` function because on platforms where `spawn` is used to create new processes, such as Windows, if I had left that statement at global scope it would have been executed anyway for each newly created process. However, for Linux, where `fork` is used to create new processes, it would not be executed for each new process and instead each new process would inherit the single database that was opened by the main process. This might or might not have worked -- you can try it both ways with the statement at global scope or not. If you put it back at global scope to see if it works there, you do not need the same statement towards the bottom of the source.

```py
from tinydb import TinyDB
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock


def run(lock, params):
    resultsDb = TinyDB('db/resultsDb.json')
    with lock:
        resultsDb.insert({'id': params['id'], 'name': params['name'], 'age': params['age']})
    print('Successfully inserted.')

# required by Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}

    maxProcesses = 12 # Cores in my pc

    lock = Lock()
    processes = []
    for i in range(maxProcesses):
        processes.append(Process(target=run, args=(lock, params)))

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # remove the following if the first one is at global scope:
    resultsDb = TinyDB('db/resultsDb.json')
    print(resultsDb.all())
```

Prints:

```
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
Successfully inserted.
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'poop', 'age': 99}]
```

Comment: Despite my description I actually left `resultsDb = TinyDB('db/resultsDb.json')` as a global statement when I had meant to move it inside function `run` (as I said, it works both ways on Windows and I tested it both ways). I have updated the source so that it matches my description above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parallelize the data write, you need to break your problem down into smaller steps so that you can ensure the step where you're inserting data has already coalesced everything together. That way you won't have any (obvious) thread safety issues on the write.

For example, suppose your JSON file has three fields, `email`, `name`, and `age` and you want to enforce uniqueness on `email`, but some records are double-entered. E.g., there's one entry that has `emily@smith.com` with her name, and another with her age.

You'd start by making something to group everything together, then parallelize the write.

I'll sketch some code (note I have not tested this!):

```
my_data = # some JSON data
grouped = {}

for datum in my_data:
    if datum['email'] in grouped:
        grouped[datum['email']].update(datum)
    else:
        grouped[datum['email']] = datum

# parallelize write as above
```

Comment: The problem isn't the parallelizing I guess. So tinyDB gives each data entry an unique 'id' (the rest of the values aren't unique) but because I'm using multiple processes sometimes he tries to add data at the exact same time. This causes that both processes for example want to add a data entry with id 5 but the last processes gets an error because this id already exists.